# What causes these reddish spotty artifacts?

Tags: artifacts

I'm just experimenting with a new lens.

Here is an image I took tonight into the sun. I was trying to capture the rays. I was surprised by the spots that appear on the grass below where the sun is situated as I've never seen an artifact like that before.  They appear to be arranged somewhat in a grid pattern, but elongate as they are farther from the source.  I'm not sure I've taken a shot like this with other lenses so it may very well be the fault of the sensor.

**My question is: what has caused these to appear and are they a product of the lens or of the sensor?**

Shot on a Fujifilm X-E1 with a 10-24mm 1:4 lens at the widest setting 10mm. The aperture is stopped way down to f/22 for 1/15sec.

[image]

[A fullsize of the image is available at this url](http://41.media.tumblr.com/bd528bce5c0b9f079d73058b9c30b3ce/tumblr_nu36wecWL21qaxrfdo1_1280.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a combination of regular lens flare plus a particular type of lens flare that can happen with some mirrorless cameras, called Red Dot Flare (https://photographylife.com/red-dot-flare-issue).

Basically, this is caused when light reflect inside the lens elements (regular lens flare) and when the light gets reflected from the imaging sensor to the lens, then back to the imaging sensor (Red Dot Flare).

It's something completely normal and expected, even if it isn't that common, so you don't need to worry - there's nothing wrong with your camera.

Comment: uh-huh. all the right conditions. it's an interesting effect.

Comment: You can try using a single-coated UV filter in front of your lens too. These effects will be more frequent then